# Cakephp 3 condition with a float value number not working

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

I am using cakePHP3 and the following is the debug of a query that i am using to get data when the unit price is equal to the pdo bind parameter.

```
'sql' => 'SELECT Dockets.id AS `Dockets__id`, Dockets.docketnum AS `Dockets__docketnum`, Branches.name AS `Branches__name`, Contacts.fname AS `Contacts__fname`, Contacts.lname AS `Contacts__lname`, Dockets.description AS `Dockets__description`, Dockets.quantity AS `Dockets__quantity`, Dockets.unitprice AS `Dockets__unitprice`, Dockets.status AS `Dockets__status`, Dockets.mailshipping AS `Dockets__mailshipping`, Dockets.mailorder AS `Dockets__mailorder`, ShippingForms.id AS `ShippingForms__id`, ShippingForms.status AS `ShippingForms__status`, VariablePrinterForms.start_prefix AS `VariablePrinterForms__start_prefix`, VariablePrinterForms.stop_prefix AS `VariablePrinterForms__stop_prefix` FROM dockets Dockets LEFT JOIN branches Branches ON Branches.id = (Dockets.branch_id) LEFT JOIN contacts Contacts ON Contacts.id = (Dockets.contact_id) LEFT JOIN shipping_forms ShippingForms ON Dockets.id = (ShippingForms.docket_id) LEFT JOIN variable_printer_forms VariablePrinterForms ON Dockets.id = (VariablePrinterForms.docket_id) LEFT JOIN lamdie_forms LamdieForms ON Dockets.id = (LamdieForms.docket_id) LEFT JOIN label_press_forms LabelPressForms ON Dockets.id = (LabelPressForms.docket_id) WHERE Dockets.unitprice = :c0 ORDER BY Dockets.docketnum desc LIMIT 25',
'params' => [
    ':c0' => [
        'value' => '56.58',
        'type' => 'float',
        'placeholder' => 'c0'
    ]
```

This query however does not return any result.
 However if I use the same query in phpmyadmin as

```
SELECT Dockets.id AS `Dockets__id`, Dockets.docketnum AS `Dockets__docketnum`, Branches.name AS `Branches__name`, Contacts.fname AS `Contacts__fname`, Contacts.lname AS `Contacts__lname`, Dockets.description AS `Dockets__description`, Dockets.quantity AS `Dockets__quantity`, Dockets.unitprice AS `Dockets__unitprice`, Dockets.status AS `Dockets__status`, Dockets.mailshipping AS `Dockets__mailshipping`, Dockets.mailorder AS `Dockets__mailorder`, ShippingForms.id AS `ShippingForms__id`, ShippingForms.status AS `ShippingForms__status`, VariablePrinterForms.start_prefix AS `VariablePrinterForms__start_prefix`, VariablePrinterForms.stop_prefix AS `VariablePrinterForms__stop_prefix` FROM dockets Dockets LEFT JOIN branches Branches ON Branches.id = (Dockets.branch_id) LEFT JOIN contacts Contacts ON Contacts.id = (Dockets.contact_id) LEFT JOIN shipping_forms ShippingForms ON Dockets.id = (ShippingForms.docket_id) LEFT JOIN variable_printer_forms VariablePrinterForms ON Dockets.id = (VariablePrinterForms.docket_id) LEFT JOIN lamdie_forms LamdieForms ON Dockets.id = (LamdieForms.docket_id) LEFT JOIN label_press_forms LabelPressForms ON Dockets.id = (LabelPressForms.docket_id) WHERE Dockets.unitprice = 56.58 ORDER BY Dockets.docketnum desc LIMIT 25
```

It returns a bunch of results. Can anyone tell me why cake is not providing any result set here. The field in the database is set to float(10,3).

The debugkit log is

```
SELECT Dockets.id AS `Dockets__id`, Dockets.docketnum AS `Dockets__docketnum`, Branches.name AS `Branches__name`, Contacts.fname AS `Contacts__fname`, Contacts.lname AS `Contacts__lname`, Dockets.description AS `Dockets__description`, Dockets.quantity AS `Dockets__quantity`, Dockets.unitprice AS `Dockets__unitprice`, Dockets.status AS `Dockets__status`, Dockets.mailshipping AS `Dockets__mailshipping`, Dockets.mailorder AS `Dockets__mailorder`, ShippingForms.id AS `ShippingForms__id`, ShippingForms.status AS `ShippingForms__status`, VariablePrinterForms.start_prefix AS `VariablePrinterForms__start_prefix`, VariablePrinterForms.stop_prefix AS `VariablePrinterForms__stop_prefix` FROM dockets Dockets LEFT JOIN branches Branches ON Branches.id = (Dockets.branch_id) LEFT JOIN contacts Contacts ON Contacts.id = (Dockets.contact_id) LEFT JOIN shipping_forms ShippingForms ON Dockets.id = (ShippingForms.docket_id) LEFT JOIN variable_printer_forms VariablePrinterForms ON Dockets.id = (VariablePrinterForms.docket_id) LEFT JOIN lamdie_forms LamdieForms ON Dockets.id = (LamdieForms.docket_id) LEFT JOIN label_press_forms LabelPressForms ON Dockets.id = (LabelPressForms.docket_id) WHERE Dockets.unitprice = 56.58 ORDER BY Dockets.docketnum desc LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

Thanks

Comment: Pardon my question but did you actually execute the query? Did you do something like `$query->toArray()`, or `$query->all()`?

Comment: Yes I did. $query->toArray() gives and empty set ([ ]).

Comment: can you debug and post the query actually executed? The one you see in the SqlLog panel of debugKit when debug mode is activated

Comment: I have edited my question to include the debugkit log.

Comment: debugkit also tells you how many rows are affected, check if it corresponds to what you are expecting. The query beeing executed is exactly the same query you tryed in phpmyadmin so it should get the same result. So I guess you are doing some other manipulation of the recordset somewere. You have to post at least a little bit of you controller code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the data type in the table was float(10,3) as searching an exact float value needs some extra functions (like FORMAT() etc) to be used in mysql query. I changed it to decimal(10,3) and it seems to search the decimal values perfectly now.